# Relation one to many with 2 foreigns keys of the same table Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a table called customers. These table has two addresses . One address of work and One direccion of house

Those 2 addresses belong to a table called addresses
I don't know how to relation those 2 tables

Migrations

```
 class CreateCustomers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :customers do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :address_id   #Address of work
      t.integer :address_id_1 #Address of home
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateAdresses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :adresses do |t|
      t.string :street
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: are you trying to do a ***customers has many address?*** if you are you should just add a `customer_id` to the address table and give it a flag like `type['home','office']`

Comment: Is there a reason addresses are in a separate table? If you'll use them mostly in the context of a customer, maybe just put them in the customers table?

Comment: But what happens if the work or home address can be shared by 2 or 3 customers  * to *

Comment: If it is shared by 2 or 3 customers then it is a many to many problem not a one to many problem. This may require a Join table but I do not recommend this way of handling addresses. Anyways my answer describes the way you should proceed with your current configuration. Just rename the column `address_id_1` and add the two `belongs_to` lines and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe this is a good approach or database design. If you want to proceed this way and not get out of the rails convention just create two columns `address_id` and `address_two_id`

and in **customer.rb**

```
belongs_to :address, class_name: "Address"
belongs_to :address_two, class_name: "Address"
```

By default rails takes the name of the foreign key and stores it in a column called "name"+"_id"

---

The better way is two have a column `customer_id` in your `Address` model and create a relation in your customer class

**customer.rb**

```
has_many :addresses
```

And you can also validate that a customer has no more than two addresses by adding this validation to

**address.rb**

```
validate :validate_two_addresses

def validate_two_addresses
  address_count = Address.where(customer_id: self.customer_id).count
  errors.add(:base, "You cannot have more than 2 addresses.") unless address_count < 3
end
```

Comment: Thanks friend. It worked well. Osama the first is cool but you recommend me the second

Comment: Yes actually I would recommend the second approach for expandability reasons. But if you have a one to many problem that one address can have many customers then you approach is okay.